# Message passing between threads to call functions in the main thread of c++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my C++ program I am calling `std::async` to make a new thread but in some point inside the thread I need to dispatch to the main thread to execute some functions.

In Objective-C there is:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self doSomething];
});
```

Is there anything similar to that in C++ without the need to use Boost or any other third-party libraries?

If not, would message passing work to send a message to the main thread in a non-blocking manner?

Comment: More data required to give an answer. That said, a wrapper class around a `std::deque`, perhaps containing `std::function`s you want run in the main context, that protects access with a `std::mutex` might be all you need. If you want the main thread to block and wait, add a `std::condition_variable`.

Comment: Why would that ever be necessary?  Show us what you want to accomplish.

Comment: C++ concurrency in action (https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action) is a good book to buy and read if you want to do multithreading in C++. To complement user4581301 comment, on Windows, you could use PostMessage to tell the UI thread to run pending functions. A similar thing could probably be done on any OS where the UI is based on a message loop.

Comment: What I am trying to make is a library in native c++ to use in iOS and Android apps.

when I try to call smth like this in my cpp testing environment or Android or iOS `Lib.fetchData(Interface i);` the delegate ( interface will fire on a background thread (due to the multithreaded nature of my problem) not on Main thread of the UI of the OS). @JiveDadson @Phil1970